# Dagger2 @Named annotation issue with rxjava subject

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, dagger-2

I am having issues with Dagger injecting the wrong BehaviorSubject. It seems like it's ignoring my @Named("") annotation when declairing the member varible. I have a semi complicated task. I need a behaviorSubject that is directly accessed in a service, put into multiple wrapper object / interfaces, which then are injected.

I am getting errors like.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors creating object graph:
      io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject required by public io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject xxxxx.android.service.xxxx.myBehaviorSubject

When trying to inject it my service.

```
@Inject
@Named(NAME)
lateinit var myBehaviorSubject: PublishSubject<MYOBJECT>
```

This first example works. But I want to do it without a member variable (as then whats the point of using dagger..) and I don't want to create a future error when someone else tries to create a subject injection.

```
PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> LPS = null;
@Provides
@Named(NAME)
@Singleton
PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> provideSubjectRx() {
    if(LPS == null){
        LPS =  PublishSubject.create();
    }
    return LPS;
 }
```

The following does not work, for some reason. Cannot build graph. This is what I want.

```
@Provides
@Named(NAME)
@Singleton
PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> provideSubjectRx(PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> LPS) 
{
    if(LPS == null){
        LPS =  PublishSubject.create();
    }
    return LPS;
}
```

I have to include this..

```
 @Provides
    PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> providePublishSubject() {
        PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        return publishSubject;
    }
```

Weird.. thats what the first function is supposed to do. Its as if Dagger doesn't want to use it for some reason...and now I get Different instances of the publish subject, which is not what I need at all. ApiProvider is built with the provideSubjectRx, then my SERVICE pulls the WRONG one, it ignores my @named annotation and calls providePublishSubject

Below builds but gives the wrong version to my service.

```
 @Provides
    @Named(NAME)
    @Singleton
    PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> provideSubjectRx(PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> LPS) 
    {
        return LPS;
    }

   @Provides
        PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> providePublishSubject() {
            PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
            return publishSubject;
        }
```

I build my wrappers like this..

The service just injects

```
@Inject
@Named(NAME)
lateinit var behaviorSubject: PublishSubject<MYOBJECT>
```

my wrapper is injected like this

```
  @Inject
    ApiProvider apiProvider;
```

and is created like this in the same dagger module..

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ApiProvider provideApiProvider(
        Context context, 
        @Named(NAME) final PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> subject) {
    return new ApiProvider(context, subject);
}
```

The only thing I can think of is I need to build my service with Dagger, but that's not really great for my architecture, and I don't own that service. I really just want to inject into it. So other than create even more wrapper objects, whats going on? This seems like pretty clear cut DI, that is going crazy.

It just seems like it thinks the correct constructor cannot be used.. if I take away the @named it still wont build. Maybe it has to do with the PublishSubject in the method signature.. but as far as I know that's how it should work. Which okay I provide how to make the subject, it doesn't explain why it's ignoring my @named

Comment: Your whole setup doesn't make much sense to me. What you're trying to achieve seems to be `@Provides @Named(NAME) @Singleton PublishSubject<MYOBJECT> provideSubjectRx() { return PublishSubject.create(); }` and nothing else. Why do you keep a field in your module? Dagger will create a scoped object only once, you won't be using the field _ever_ like this. And why inject an unnamed version to provide a named variant? If you do this you will need a second method to provide the unnamed variant, as you found out.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the @Named, I ended up just giving up and doing a simple implementation like yours, and hoping no one else will need to use a PublishSubject<MYOBJECT>